# How to add timer in c++?

Tags: c++, timer

I am making a c++ project having a login program. I want to add timer such that if the user enters login details wrong three times then user have to wait for 10 minutes. Can anyone suggest a way?

Comment: Did any of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a timer. You may do a delay.
This is how it works on windows

```
#include "windows.h"
Sleep(5000);
```

and how on linux

```
#include <unistd.h>
sleep(5);
```

Comment: You can use `std::this_thread::sleep_for` to get a standard C++ solution that works everywhere since C++11.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a timer, but you should keep the time when the third attempt occured inside a map where the key is the username.

Each time the user try to enter the password you should check if he has been blacklisted by the map giving him a warning message.

By this approach you allow different users to gain the access inside the same session.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock).

```
#include <chrono>

// ...

std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point timer_start;

// start the timer when you want
timer_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    
// then check if the time has passed later:
std::chrono::duration time_passed;
    
time_passed = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - timer_start;

if(time_passed < std::chrono::minutes(10)) {
    // not allowed in yet        
}
```